# Is my reasoning about the handshaking lemma right?

Tags: graph-theory, self-learning

I am being asked this:

> Prove that it is impossible to have a group of 55 people at a party
>   such that each one is a friend with exactly five of the others in the
>   group.

I don't know if my reasoning is okay. I just want to check it here.

So, I like to think like this...

We have 55 people, so that means we have 55 vertices. Each of them have exactly 5 friends, which means they have 5 edges.

The theory says:

> The number of vertices with an odd degree must be even

So, 55 is not even while it has an odd degree (5), thus: this is impossible.

Am I correct? **Am I also correct if I'd say that this would be possible if there were 56 people with 5 edges?**

Comment: Your reasoning is correct ... Think about a smaller example, three people at a party & each person is friends with exactly one person ? ...

Comment: Thank you Sir! Good to know this!